# Access Rights for Page In openerp 7

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, code-access-security, access-rights

I want to give readonly permission to "Contacts" page which is inside res_partner I inherited that view and in my new xml I mentioned
grp_partner -> my module name
group_readonly_supplier -> I created one group inside that module having only read permission to res_partner

XML code :

```
< xpath expr="//page[@string='Internal Notes']" position="replace" >
< page string="Internal Notes" 
attrs = "{'readonly':[('groups','=','grp_partner.group_readonly_supplier')]}" >
< /page >
< /xpath >
```

but whenever I clicked on edit I got blank page Then I tried

```
< xpath expr="//page[@string='Internal Notes']" position="replace" >
< page string="Internal Notes" 
attrs="{'readonly': [('groups','=','hcapex_partner.group_hcapex_supplier')]}" >
< field name="comment" placeholder="Put an internal note..." 
 attrs="{'readonly': [('groups','=','grp_partner.group_readonly_supplier')]}"/ >                                   
< /page >
< /xpath >
```

But this will also not able to make readonly that field from that Page.

Please Help me

Thank You in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 'field_name': fields.char('Field Name', size=64,write= ['base.group_partner_manager'],read=['base.group_user']),
```

or this:

Create a functional field in your model which will be true if the user belong to the specified group else false, then add `attrs` for your field to make it editable if the user belong to the specified group else readonly.

Comment: Is there any possibility to do same task through xml or csv file?